# How to Make a Stacked Area Chart from an existing Area chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a requirement to take an existing area chart and convert it into a stacked area chart. I've looked at the D3 API and several other examples of Stacked Area charts but I cannot seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

The API (d3.stack) appears to be pretty straight forward and clear but I'm clearly missing something.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code for the existing (working) area chart:

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30 };
var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
       .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

d3.json('data.json', function (err, data) {
    var data = data.employees;

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y/%m/%d');

    data.forEach(name => {
        name.values.forEach(d => {
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.volume = d.volume;
        });
    });
    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([
            d3.min(data, nm => d3.min(nm.values, d => d.date)),
            d3.max(data, nm => d3.max(nm.values, d => d.date))
        ])
        .range([0, width])

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([
            d3.min(data, nm => d3.min(nm.values, d => d.volume)),
            d3.max(data, nm => d3.max(nm.values, d => d.volume))
        ])
        .range([height, 0])

    var area = d3.area()
        .x(d => xScale(d.date))
        .y0(yScale(yScale.domain()[0]))
        .y1(d => yScale(d.volume))
        .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom);

   //var stack = d3.stack()
     //   .keys(["Employee1", "Employee2"])     
     //   .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
     //   .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

     //   var stackAttempt = stack(data);
     //   console.log(stackAttempt);

    svg.selectAll('.area')
        //.data(stackAttempt)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'area')
        .attr('d', d => area(d.values))
        .style('stroke', (d, i) => ['#22556E', '#6DB3BF'][i])
        .style('stroke-width', 2)
        .style('fill', (d, i) => ['#22556E', '#6DB3BF'][i])
        .style('fill-opacity', 0.3);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .attr("class", "axisSteel")
        .style('stroke-width', 3)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10));

    svg.append('g')
        .attr("class", "axisSteel")
        .style('stroke-width', 3)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))

})
```

With this JSON format:

```
{
"employees": [
        {
            "name": "Employee1",
            "values": [
                {
                "volume": 17,
                "date": "2018/09/10"
                },{
                "volume": 20,
                "date": "2018/09/11"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Employee2",
            "values": [
                {
                "volume": 10,
                "date": "2018/09/10"
                },{
                "volume": 29,
                "date": "2018/08/11"
                }
            ]
        },
}
```

Comment: where in your code do you call `d3.stack`?

Comment: Sure no problem, I've edited to show where I add d3.stack just below d3.area (commented out) and then call it at svg.selectAll('.area'). also (commented out) since it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your input data.

`d3.stack` doesn't like the pre-nested data, most starting data for `d3` is flat like this:

```
[{
  "name": "Employee1",
  "volume": 17,
  "date": "2018/09/10"
}, {
  "name": "Employee1",
  "volume": 20,
  "date": "2018/09/11"
}, {
  "name": "Employee2",
  "volume": 10,
  "date": "2018/09/10"
}, {
  "name": "Employee2",
  "volume": 29,
  "date": "2018/08/11"
}]
```

Then the stack call becomes:

```
 var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(["Employee1", "Employee2"])     
    .value(function(d,k) { return d.volume; })
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);
```

And the area generator:

```
var area = d3.area()
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(d.data.date); })
  .y0(function(d) { return yScale(d[0]); })
  .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was afraid that was the problem. I’ll make the appropriate corrections. Thanks again!